# Name for $d$ in the equation $\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{n}=d$ that describes a plane

Tags: vectors, terminology

We can describe a plane by $$\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{n}=d,$$ where $\mathbf{n}$ is the plane's normal vector and $d$ is a constant.

Is there an even somewhat-standard name for the constant $d$?

Comment: "Distance from the origin"? See equations $(7)$ through $(14)$ [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Plane.html)

Comment: if $n$ is a unit vector, then $d$ is the signed distance between the plane and origin.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire, achille hui: Yes, if $|\mathbf{n}|=1$, then we do have that interpretation. But what about more generally? That is, if $|\mathbf{n}|\neq1$, what might we call $d$?